# CSS IntelliSense for class names suggesting old, deleted classes generated by css-modules

Tags: css, reactjs, visual-studio-code, intellisense, css-modules

I am currently the migrating the styling of my project from css-modules to tailwindcss.
I used @apply to create my own classes within `index.css`. The problem is, these classes aren't suggested by the intellisense of VSCode Extension. Instead, it keeps suggesting classes like `Card_Button_43eDg` which seems like the ones generated by css-modules even though I have already removed all the `.module.css` files. I tried clearing CSS class caches but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Any suggestions to make the intellisense show the correct class names?

[This](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Zignd.html-css-class-completion) is the extension I use.

edit: I have the official talwindcss extension installed as well.
The autocompeletion for utility classes are present but not for my own class declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend installing https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bradlc.vscode-tailwindcss. This plugin is from official Tailwind docs, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/editor-setup.

I have both plugins installed and I have the auto complete feature.

Comment: I forgot to mention but I have that installed too, still no autocomplete